# mysql str_to_date で生成した date カラムが pymysql で型がかわってしまう

Tags: python, mysql

```
import pymysql
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('mysql.ini', encoding='utf-8')
config = config['DEFAULT']

mysql = pymysql.connect(**config)
with mysql.cursor() as cursor:
  sql =f'''
SELECT str_to_date('20210316', "%Y%m%d"), str_to_date('486200304T090000Z', "%Y%m%d")
      '''
  cursor.execute(sql)
  results = cursor.fetchall()
  print(results)
```

を実行すると

```
((datetime.date(2021, 3, 16), '4862-00-30'),)
```

という感じでイレギュラーな文字を入れると文字列になったり date になったりします
このデータをまた別のDBにインサートするときに型エラーが出てしまうのですが
処理環境の問題から python 側でデータの型を１つ１つチェックするのはできれば避けたいです

MySQL 側で date にならないものは None にしたいのですが
どういう条件ではじけばいいでしょうか

ちなみに homebrew で @5.7 でいれた MySQL 5.7.26 では NULL になってくれるのですが
AWS RDS 上の 5.7.12 では '4862-00-30' となってしまいます

なのでバージョンあげれば解決する問題なんですが
バージョン変更となると大規模な動作確認が必要になるのでいまの 5.7.12 上で動くようにしたいです

---

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects
python のドキュメントを見ると

```
MINYEAR <= year <= MAXYEAR

1 <= month <= 12

1 <= day <= 指定された月と年における日数
```

となってるんですが pymysql が中でどう変換してるのかは調べてもわかりませんでした

mysql 側でこういうフィルターを簡単にかける方法はないでしょうか

Comment: 参考: [How to check if a string is a valid DATE, TIME or DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2690205)

Comment: 手元の MySQL 8.0 で試してみたところ、`sqlmode` に [NO_ZERO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) が含まれていると `select str_to_date('486200304T090000Z', "%Y%m%d");` が `NULL` になります。

Comment: バージョンのせいではなくコンフィグの違いだったのですね。set session sql_mode='NO_ZERO_DATE' してみたら None になってくれました！